# Using Python's parallel programming facilities to process data files

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a list of files through a program in parallel using python.

To abstract the real reason I'm doing this I've written a small command line program called `fake_program.py` which accepts as argument a text file containing an arbitrary list of numbers separated by a comma. The program adds the numbers and prints the result.

`fake_program.py`:

```
import argparse
##parse arguments from command line 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

## read data file
with open(args.filename) as f:
    numbers = f.read()

## process and add the numbers 
numbers = numbers.split(',')
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers)
```

Example input files:

`data_file_1.txt` contains:

```
1, 2, 3
```

`data_file2.txt` contains

```
4, 5, 6
```

`data_file3.txt` contains

```
7, 8, 9
```

With usage:

```
$ python fake_program.py data_file1.txt
```

`output`:

```
6
```

My objective is to process these three files (or an arbitrary number of similar files) through `fake_program.py` in parallel. Note that for this simple example it would be enough to simply run separate instances of `fake_program.py` to get all the data processed. However, the program I'm really running is computationally heavy and becomes unresponsive at around 8 instances. Since I'm running around 400 data files through the program and each one can take up to 5 minutes to process it would be good to introduce a `Queue` such that (say) 5 data files can be processed at once and when one finished another begins.

Here is the script so far:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
import Queue
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import glob

def run1(q, fle):
    """
    Process 1 file 
    :return: 
    """
    args = ['python', 'fake_program.py', '"{}"'.format(fle)]
    proc = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                 stderr=PIPE, shell=False)

    q.put(proc, block=True)



def run_all(files):
    """

    """
    number_of_processes = cpu_count()
    q = Queue.Queue(number_of_processes)
    result = []
    for fle in files:
        t = Thread(target=run1, args=(q, fle))
        t.start()
        q.join()
        result.append(q.get())
    return result   

if __name__=='__main__':
    working_directory = </my/working/directory>
    data_files = glob.glob(working_directory+'\*.txt')
    print data_files
    print run_all(data_files)
```

This program currently just hangs infinitely. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this parallelism?

Comment: The simplest thing is to just split your data and run three instances of the program, something that you can trivially orchestrate with a short shell script.

Comment: Yes, but this is an abstraction of another problem I'm dealing with - the `fake_program` is really a `c++` command line program that does the heavy lifting. Therefore I *have to run the program this way. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Maybe you should describe your actual problem instead of 'an abstraction of another problem in C++'? Presumably you want a solution rather than abstraction of a solution.

Comment: ... I have. I'm trying do this in python not C++. Just the 3rd party program I'm using is c++, i.e `fake_program.py` is really an executable (sorry about the mislead)

Comment: Right but that doesn't explain why you can't just start three instances of your program. Use python to merge the results, if you have to, use shell to orchestrate processes. It's good at it.

Comment: Ah, yes. I did this first. The problem is that its computationally heavy. I can run about 8-10 instances of the program before my computer slows and becomes unusable. Ideally I'd have the queuing system in place to have (say) 5 processes crunching numbers at any one time.

Comment: If it's computationally heavy, only run as many as you can before your computer melts or starts becoming non-responsive. It's still not clear what the python is actually trying to achieve. Edit your question to add this stuff from the comments and whatever other details (how long is a typical invocation of the c++ program? etc)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe use multiprocessing.Pool instead of Queue. It's pretty simple to use if your jobs are asynchronous. Also, if your subprocess throws an exception, Python multiprocessing may not be smart enough to return it to the main process. I've seen hanging before in this scenario.